# $_POST is not appearing in the URL until the second submission of my form

Tags: php, forms, post, url-rewriting

I have a select box which issues a $_POST command once the user changes the selection in order to filter my results by their category.

The results display correctly however their is one small error which is bugging me...When I change the field and the post submits the URL does not have the variable appended to it, however when I change the selection again the previous variable is appended to my URL.

Below is my code...

## QUERY CODE

```
    <?php 
    $post_cat = $_POST['position'];
    $node_id = 0;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'jobs',
        'category_name' => $post_cat 
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $output = get_output($post_cat);

?>
```

## HTML CODE

```
<form name="job_select" action="?post_cat=<?php echo $post_cat ?>"  method="post">
                <select class="job_cats" onchange="job_select.submit();" name="position">
                        <option style="display:none">Browse Job Categories...</option>
                         <?php 
                              $job = get_categories('16');
                                $option = '<option value="jobs">';
                                $option .= "All Careers";
                                $option .= '</option>';
                                echo $option;

                              // For every child of blog
                              $categories =  get_categories('child_of=16'); 
                              foreach ($categories as $category) {
                                $option = '<option value="'.$category->category_nicename.'">';
                                $option .= $category->cat_name;
                                $option .= '</option>';
                                echo $option;
                              }
                         ?> 
                </select>
            </form>
```

If anybody has any inclings as to why the URL append is delayed by one round of submissions then I'd be most grateful, thanks for your time.

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this part is incorrect: `action="?post_cat=<?php echo $post_cat ?>"`
because the first time you load the page, this becomes `action="?post_cat="` and each subsequent time your action is defined as the previous choice.
you perhaps want `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` as your action, to call this same page again.  Then after the form is submitted you have the value chosen in the PHP array `$_POST`.  Variables passed in the URL are found in the `$_GET` array.  It's like you're doing both.  With `method="POST"` you don't need to pass them into the URL.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that for me Joe, I got it to work once you pointed that out.  I guess its true when they say that if you stare at something for so long you can't see the flaws in your logic!

Answer (score 1):

There is a small problem in the logic: You do a post request to a page that has the current category as a query parameter:

```
<form name="job_select" action="?post_cat=<?php echo $post_cat ?>"  method="post">
```

In your php you get the correct value of the posted variable, but the url you are posting and that is displaying, is the previous one.

It would probably be easier to just use `GET` but if you really want to use `POST` you would have to redirect to the correct url after you have processed the `POST` variable.

Comment: Yes Jeroen, that was the problem.  Thank-you for your input!

Answer (score -1):

try to get the post variable by '$_REQUEST' not '$_POST' in your query. The POST method won't display the value in url, it would be GET method, so the displayed url cannot be submited into '$_POST' variable

Comment: the page will still be behind by one selection because of the logic of the form action

Comment: In the `GET` array you will only find a static value that was appended the previous time was loaded, not the actual posted value.